# Extract certain parts of nested lists of a list to create a dataframe

Tags: r

Below I apply shapiro test on the first 4 columns of `iris` dataset. I would like to create a dataframe out of this with the column name, the p value and the w score.

```
apply(iris,2,shapiro.test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df <- apply(iris[,1:4], 2, function(x) {
  sh <- shapiro.test(x)
  c(p = sh$p.value, sh$statistic)})

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width
p   0.01018116   0.1011543 7.412263e-10 1.680465e-08
W   0.97609027   0.9849179 8.762681e-01 9.018349e-01
```

You can make it tidy dataframe as follow:

```r
library(tidyverse)
as.data.frame(df) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "stats") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -stats)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  stats name            value
  <chr> <chr>           <dbl>
1 p     Sepal.Length 1.02e- 2
2 p     Sepal.Width  1.01e- 1
3 p     Petal.Length 7.41e-10
4 p     Petal.Width  1.68e- 8
5 W     Sepal.Length 9.76e- 1
6 W     Sepal.Width  9.85e- 1
7 W     Petal.Length 8.76e- 1
8 W     Petal.Width  9.02e- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply`.

```
sapply(iris[-5], \(x) shapiro.test(x)[1:2])
#           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width 
# statistic 0.9760903    0.9849179   0.8762681    0.9018349   
# p.value   0.01018116   0.1011543   7.412263e-10 1.680465e-08
```

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
map(iris[-5], shapiro.test) %>% 
  map_df(broom::glance, .id = "vars")  
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   vars         statistic  p.value method                     
#>   <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                      
#> 1 Sepal.Length     0.976 1.02e- 2 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 2 Sepal.Width      0.985 1.01e- 1 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 3 Petal.Length     0.876 7.41e-10 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 4 Petal.Width      0.902 1.68e- 8 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>